# HeightForRowAt indexPath issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I' m working to an e-commerce app and I have an issue when trying to set the height of a specific row. When I choose the category the table reloads and depending on the category i choosed more or less rows are coming through the api.

So with this setup it s working when i select a specific category but when i choose another it will mess my rows and will increase the height to another

```
let firstCellHeight:CGFloat = 265
let addBtnCellHeight:CGFloat = 60
let phoneCellHeight: CGFloat = 95

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let cellIdentifier = self.tableCells[indexPath.row]
    let height:CGFloat!

    switch cellIdentifier {
        case "AddAdImagesCell":
            height = self.firstCellHeight
        case "AddBtnCell":
            height = self.addBtnCellHeight
        case "ExtraFieldCell":
            if indexPath.row == 4 {
              height = self.phoneCellHeight
            } else {
                height = 44
        }


        default:
            height = 44
    }

    return height
}
```

For the cell for row i m having this code:

```
 case "ExtraFieldCell":
            let currentField = self.extraFields[indexPath.row - self.firstExtraFieldIndex]

            switch currentField.type {
                case "select":
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraFieldSelectCell")!

                    if currentField.name == "area" 

                    return cell
                case "text":
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraFieldTextCell") as! FiltersTFCell
                    cell.label.text = "\(currentField.label):"


                    return cell
                case "checkbox":
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraFieldCheckboxCell") as! CheckboxCell

                    cell.fieldLabel.text = currentField.label


                    return cell
                default:
                    let cell = UITableViewCell()
                    return cell
            }
```

So how to set the height 95 always for the row with the `case "text"`

Comment: When you chose an other category did you call `reloadData()` ?

Comment: Yes. everytime , and also a function which set the extra fields

Comment: Where do you put the values in `tableCells`? Is this your actual code? Your cell dequeue code would crash since it doesn't allow for the `nil` that will be returned the first time a cell is dequeued with that form of the dequeue function.

Comment: i do but there s a lot of code i didnt want to link it all here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `self.tableView.rowHeight` when setting the cell, I tried to apply with your example code below, if you have any questions call me back.

```
case "ExtraFieldCell":
        let currentField = self.extraFields[indexPath.row - self.firstExtraFieldIndex]

        switch currentField.type {
            case "select":
                self.tableView.rowHeight = firstCellHeight
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraFieldSelectCell")!

                if currentField.name == "area" 

                return cell
            case "text":
                self.tableView.rowHeight = addBtnCellHeight
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraFieldTextCell") as! FiltersTFCell
                cell.label.text = "\(currentField.label):"


                return cell
            case "checkbox":
                self.tableView.rowHeight = phoneCellHeight
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExtraFieldCheckboxCell") as! CheckboxCell

                cell.fieldLabel.text = currentField.label


                return cell
            default:
                self.tableView.rowHeight = 44
                let cell = UITableViewCell()
                return cell
        }
```

importantly, when is test comment or remove this method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { ... }
```